# How to view the content of a moved file submitted for modification

Tags: git

I use the `git log --follow` command to view the submission history of a file, but I enter the `git show <cmmid> <file name>` command, which returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

- `git log` can take the `-p|--patch` option to display the diff of each commit it selects
- `git show` also accepts the `--follow` option

```
git log --follow -p -- path/to/file.new
# to display only one commit :
git log --follow -p -1 <commitid> -- path/to/file.new

git show --follow <commitid> -- path/to/file.new
```

---

You can also provide the name of the file before and after the renaming :

```
git log -p -- path/to/file.old path/to/file.new

git show <commitid> -- path/to/file.old path/to/file.new
```

---

[edit]

If your intention is to review the changes introduced by a specific pull request (if your central repo is a `github/azure devops/gitlab/...` instance) :

One way to view the same diff, on your local repo, as the one you see in your web GUI is :

```
git diff master...feature/branch   # 3 dots, not a typo
```

The "3 dots" notation for `git diff` is a shortcut to say "from the merge base of both branches" ([link to docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203-1)).

If you want to view the diff for a specific file, even when that file was renamed during the fork, `git diff` also understands the `--follow` option :

```
git diff --follow master...feature/branch -- path/to/file.new
```

Comment: Git log -- follow - p -- path/to/file.new can display all the submitted information of this file,
But use git show -- follow<committed>-- path/to/file New still returns no results

Comment: `git log` will scan through the history of the commit, `git show` will look only at the commit id you provide and not scan any parent. If you don't provide the *exact* commitid where `path/to/file` was changed, it won't display any changes. Do you confirm that, in your `git show` command , you used the exact same commit id that is displayed by your `git log` command ?

Comment: if your need is to review the change for a pull request (or something similar), see my edit. The `git diff base...branch` trick will allow you to skip the "spot the correct commit id" part, and will also show you the complete diff between `base` and `branch` (even if modifications are spread over several commits)

Comment: I reconstructed the project and put the files in different folders. After a period of time, I found that when I used the git log path/to/fileName command, it did not display the previous submission information. After I entered the git log -- follow path/to/fileName command, it displayed the previous submission information, but when I used the git show commitId path/to/fileName command, it did not return any information

Comment: is your intention to : 1. review the complete history of changes on that file ? or 2. review the changes on that file for a specific feature or pull request ?

Comment: Check what changes have been made to this file through the commitId

Comment: does "through" mean a. "in that commit only" or b. "in that commit and any of its parents" ? (if 'a.' : use `git show`, if 'b.' use `git log`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248344/discussion-between-smile-and-legec).